# Java code for getting Eastern date and time as date format to insert into database

Tags: java

I am using the java code like below to get the current eastern date and time and it should be inserted to database in date format. Using the below code I am able to get the eastern date and time in string format as expected, but I can't insert this string format in SQL database because the column being used in database to store is of type datetime. I also tried changing the formatted Eastern time zone date and time to date type but it returns the date and time in GMT format again.

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
java.util.Date time = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.ms");
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"); 
formatter.setTimeZone(timeZone);

System.out.println("EST: " + formatter.format(time)); // Prints date as 2016-03-18 03:12:16.1216 which is string format

java.util.Date time1 = formatter.parse(formatter.format(time));

System.out.println("EST Time Zone: " + time1); // Prints date as Fri Mar 18 07:04:36 GMT 2016 which is date format

//Code to insert into database
dataSource = DataSourceFactoryUtil.initDataSource("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver",
PortletProps.get("exampledatabase.db.url"), PortletProps.get("exampledatabase.db.user"),
PortletProps.get("exampledatabase.db.password"), StringPool.BLANK);

connection = dataSource.getConnection();
stmt = connection.createStatement();
String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO [exampletable] ([Firstname], [Lastname], [address], [Time]) VALUES ('"
                        + firstname + "', '" + lastname + "', '" + address + "', '" + time1 + "')";
stmt.executeUpdate(insertQuery);
```

In above code, the first System.out.println is printing the date in EST which is as expected to be inserted in database, but I can't insert it as it is in string type, and I get the error as:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

Another System.out.println gives the output in date format but it is not in EST.

How is it possible to get the output as format 2016-03-18 03:12:16.1216, and in date type instead of string so that I can insert into the database which has datetime type as a column.

Comment: A Java `Date` only stores a number of milliseconds since epoch (January 1, 1970 at midnight UTC). Thus, it is *always* going to display (without formatting) as GMT.

Comment: Please include the code you are using to do the insert.  As @alisson-vieira says, you need to do the insert using a Date instead of a String.

Comment: I have updated my code to show how I am doing insertion. Please see edited code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to get date and time in EST datetime format with these 2 lines of codes:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
```

I get the output as EST date and time: 2016-03-23 03:12:16.1216

Here is the working code including the code that I had provided while asking the question:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());

//Code to insert into database
dataSource = DataSourceFactoryUtil.initDataSource("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver",
PortletProps.get("exampledatabase.db.url"), PortletProps.get("exampledatabase.db.user"),
PortletProps.get("exampledatabase.db.password"), StringPool.BLANK);

connection = dataSource.getConnection();
stmt = connection.createStatement();
String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO [exampletable] ([Firstname], [Lastname], [address], [Time]) VALUES ('"
                        + firstname + "', '" + lastname + "', '" + address + "', '" + timestamp + "')";
stmt.executeUpdate(insertQuery);
```

Answer (score 4):

The [Answer by Alisson Vieira](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36093149/642706) is correct but uses outmoded classes.

Do not use strings for date-time values, use date-time types.

Do not use the old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java, such as java.util.Date/.Calendar. They have proven to be poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome. Those classes have been supplanted by the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later.

A `java.time.Instant` is a moment on the timeline in UTC. You should do most of your work, your business logic, your database storage, in UTC. Use a time zone only when required by the user or data sink.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

Eventually the JDBC drivers will be updated to deal directly with the java.time types. Until then we must continue to depend on the java.sql types for transferring data in/out of the database. But minimize your use of these classes; convert to java.time as soon as possible in your work flow.

In your database use the standard [`TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Data_types) type to define the date-time column, or the equivalent if your database is not compliant. You should almost [never use the `without time zone`](http://justatheory.com/computers/databases/postgresql/use-timestamptz.html) type.

The `java.sql.Timestamp` class maps to the `java.time.Instant` type. To this old class a few new methods have been added for conversion to/from java.time such as [`toInstant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#toInstant--) and [`from( Instant )`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#from-java.time.Instant-).

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = java.sql.Timestamp.from( instant );
```

You should always use [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to interact with your database for multiple reasons. One very important reason is to eliminate the risk of [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

```
myPreparedStatement.setTimestamp( 4 , ts );
```

To retrieve use a `java.sql.Timestamp` to get the data, then convert to java.time.

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = myResultSet.getTimestamp( 4 );
Instant instant = ts.toInstant();
```

Notice that nowhere in the code above did we deal with any particular timezone. We use [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) all the way through, Java ↔ JDBC ↔ SQL ↔ Database. And nowhere did we use Strings for our date-time values.

To see the [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time) for a particular time zone, apply a time zone ([`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html)) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). Use proper time zone names, never the 3-4 letter codes such as `EST` as these are neither standardized nor unique.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
```

To see a textual representation of that date-time value in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, merely call `toString`. Example output: `2016-03-17T05:19:24.679Z`.

```
String output = zdt.toString();
```

To generate strings in other formats, [search Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java%20DateTimeFormatter) for many examples on using [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(time1.getTime());
```

Try to use the `java.sql.Date` type into your insert SQL.

How you're attempting to insert the record? Are you using some library?

@Edit

The `System.out.print()` doesn't handles the date as the JDBC does. The first calls the `toString()` method of Date instance, and the JDBC uses the `getTime()`, aka the milliseconds representation of the Date.

@Edit2

Change `stmt = connection.createStatement();`

to

```
PreparedStatement stmt=connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO exampleTable (Firstname, Lastname, address, Time) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
stmt.setString(1, firstname);
stmt.setString(2, lastname);
stmt.setString(3, address);
stmt.setTimestamp(4, new java.sql.Date(time1.getTime()));
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: I have updated with the code that I am using to insert into the database in my edited code above.